# Prompt on the last cell of the table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want UITableView always has the text "No more items" in the last cell, I want this row appears regardless of number of items, include 0 items. How could I do?

Comment: you dont want to use `- (UIView *)tableView:tableView viewForFooterInSection:section` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total row of a section by using `numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

```
NSInteger total = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
// Check if last cell or no cell.
if(indexPath.row == totalRow -1 || indexPath.row == 0) 
{
    // Do your operation here
}
```

You can perform this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `willDisplayCell` methods. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, even if your code is not exactly right. But you give a clue.

Comment: @JasonMa Yeah, the code is not exactly right. Just wanted to give you an idea on how to get the last cell. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the row regardless of your other items:

```
- (void)buildMenu {
    [_menuItems removeAllObjects];
    // ... add your items or not if you have 0
    YourCellItem *lastItem = [[YourCellItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"No more items"];
    [_menuItems addObject:lastItem];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _menuItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"yourCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    YourTableViewCell *basicCell = (YourTableViewCell *)cell;
    YourCellItem *item = [_menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    basicCell.itemTitle.text = item.title;

    return cell;
}
```